# Corporate Email account on Cyanogenmod 7 - Encryption required

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, htc-wildfire

Has anyone got a corporate email account working with a server that requires Encryption.
I'm using a Wildfire with CM 7 and get the error

```
"This server requires features your Android device does not support"
```

I even upgraded to CM 9 but the Wildfire is extremely slow even before encryption (I guess it being a single-core processor) - and I left the phone overnight for encryption and it just does not complete. It shows the little green guy icon forever.

does anyone have any suggestions on whether

a) Encryption is possible in CM7. Seems not as far as I can see.

b) How to get Wildfire working with CM9 with encrypted email server access. Can I use any 3rd party app to encrypt the /data mount instead of in-built ICS encryption?

Comment: Yes. CM9 used to encrypt tablet (Galaxy Tab 10.1 wifi) without issue. Now encryption does nothing except appear to be encrypting. It is worthless.